# GTM server side and GA4 user location

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

While implementing GA4 with GTM server side all users are reported from same location where server instance is located.

In Universal Analytics there was uid parameter to send users IP and in UA tag it’s added. But for GA4 no such parameter added and I can’t find it in parameter reference.

Maybe it’s available but not documented yet?

Answer (score 1):

GA4 Measurement Protocol does not support setting user IP in the payload. That's why for now there no way to correctly track user location thru the server side.

A few months ago, I created an issue in Google Bug Tracker according to this.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179160710

It will be great if more people vote for this feature there.